# Unable to open Chrome Debugger for React Native App in because of flipper waring Attempting to debug JS in Flipper (deprecated)

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, remote-debugging, flipper

Bug Report

- When attempting to open the new react native app default app and
  trying to debug in Chrome debugger, users encounter an error message
  stating in terminal: "Attempting to debug JS in Flipper (deprecated).

**This requires Flipper to be installed on your system to handle the 'flipper://' URL scheme." This prevents users from efficiently    debugging their React Native apps using Chrome Debugger through    Flipper.**

**To Reproduce**
Sure, here are the steps you provided converted into a numbered list:

Open a new React Native application in development mode. (CLI)

1. Start the application and ensure it's running on a device or simulator.
2. try to open debugger (CLT+M) in Android simulator to open Chrome debugger browser.
3. after getting warring Attempting to debug JS in Flipper (deprecated). This requires Flipper to be installed on your system
4. to handle the 'flipper://' URL scheme.**
5. Unable to Navigate to the Chrome Debugger tool.
6. Unable Attempt to connect to the running React Native app for debugging.
   **Environment**
   **React Native Latest version 0.73 (CLI)**

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqMYB.png)

if anyone also encounter this same issue so how they resolve it and what the solutions for this issue?

Comment: The aim is to get rid of Flipper completely I assume and use [React Devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-devtools) instead, because [RN announced Flipper will not be supported anymore](https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/blob/main/proposals/0641-decoupling-flipper-from-react-native-core.md).

I am facing the same issue as [Om Prakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23457212/om-prakash)
I uninstalled Flipper and removed all related code but get the same error when trying to open debugger from the device debug menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) installed on your desktop/laptop. This way, when you try to debug your app, it will launch the debugger in Flipper instead of launching it in Chrome.

You can read more about this and the deprecation warning in the official docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#opening-the-debugger